# OpenCV/C++ - Convert a gray picture to BGR picture after some images process

Tags: c++, opencv, video, colors

I'm working on a project which consist to stabilize a video.
Therefore, during the process of stabilization, i had to convert my frames to gray in order to use some methods like goodFeaturesToTrack() or opticalFlow().

But at the end of my process, after applying my last transformation using warpAffine(), i would like to recover the colour information of the frame but i'm not able to do this. I tried some things.

- I try cvtColor(outFrame,outFrame,CV_GRAY2BGR) but not working (obviously). Still back and white
- At the beginning of the loop, i picked up the three colour channels B G R of my original picture like that:

  Mat channel[3];

  split(frameColor, channel);

And then at the end of the process, i'm doing that:

```
 merge(channel,3,outFrame);
```

So i have the colour of my frame but not stabilized , that is to say it's like merging channels has removed all the transformation.

- I also try to use the warpAffine() function with the colour picture but i have the same result of above.

Please help me.

Thank.

Comment: Maybe you should try do your loop for gray image as at original pipeline and then  apply warpAffine to color image (by every channel). Optical flow/Features returns information that relevant for both color and gray images. Can you provide more information about stabilization process? Sorry for my bad English

Comment: I also tried to use the warp function with the original colour frame but it's the same result: video is not stabilized whereas if i used the black and white picture, it works well. I've edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem.

Actually when you apply a transformation like warpAffine(), you have to apply it on the previous frame and not the current. I didn't notice that i applied it to my current color frame and not the previous colour frame. And therefore, there was no changement.

By applying it on my previous colour frame, the image is in colour and stabilized.